# Django Raw Query Output Inconsistent with pgAdmin Output

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using django with a postgres 10 db engine to build a web based search tool via forms. When executing the queries via raw SQL in django I only receive 3 records as opposed to 902 when running the same SQL in the Ouery Tool of pgAdmin.

I've tried using the django ORM to build my queries but the examples are so simple I haven't been able to successfully utilize it for my needs. Guidance on querying multiple models in the manner below would be appreciated.

Django Raw SQL statement

```
ProstateUpper = 'Prostate'
ProstateLower = 'prostate'
GenderMale = 'Male'
GenderAll = 'All'

Master_Query = Eligibilities.objects.raw('''SELECT DISTINCT ON (Eligibilities.nct_id) Eligibilities.id, Studies.brief_title, Eligibilities.nct_id, Conditions.name, Eligibilities.gender, Eligibilities.minimum_age, Eligibilities.maximum_age, Eligibilities.criteria, Interventions.intervention_type, Interventions.name, Facilities.city, Facilities.state, Facilities.country, Brief_Summaries.description, Facility_Contacts.name, Facility_Contacts.email FROM Eligibilities INNER JOIN Studies on Studies.nct_id = Eligibilities.nct_id INNER JOIN Conditions on Conditions.nct_id = Eligibilities.nct_id INNER JOIN Interventions on Interventions.nct_id = Eligibilities.nct_id INNER JOIN Facilities on Facilities.nct_id = Eligibilities.nct_id INNER JOIN Brief_Summaries on Brief_Summaries.nct_id = Eligibilities.nct_id INNER JOIN Facility_Contacts on Facility_Contacts.nct_id = Eligibilities.nct_id WHERE ((Conditions.name LIKE %s OR Conditions.name LIKE %s)) AND (gender LIKE %s OR gender LIKE %s) ''', [ProstateUpper, ProstateLower, GenderMale, GenderAll])[:1000]
```

pgAdmin SQL statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (eligibilities.nct_id) eligibilities.id, studies.brief_title, eligibilities.nct_id, conditions.name, eligibilities.gender, eligibilities.minimum_age, eligibilities.maximum_age, eligibilities.criteria, interventions.intervention_type, interventions.name, facilities.city, facilities.state, facilities.country, brief_summaries.description, facility_contacts.name, facility_contacts.email
FROM ctgov.eligibilities
INNER JOIN ctgov.studies on studies.nct_id = eligibilities.nct_id
INNER JOIN ctgov.conditions on conditions.nct_id = eligibilities.nct_id
INNER JOIN ctgov.interventions on interventions.nct_id = eligibilities.nct_id
INNER JOIN ctgov.facilities on facilities.nct_id = eligibilities.nct_id
INNER JOIN ctgov.brief_summaries on brief_summaries.nct_id = eligibilities.nct_id
INNER JOIN ctgov.facility_contacts on facility_contacts.nct_id = eligibilities.nct_id
WHERE ((conditions.name LIKE '%Prostate%' OR conditions.name LIKE '%prostate%')) AND (gender LIKE '%Male%' OR gender LIKE '%All%')
;
```

I expect the output to be the same amount and content of records since they're querying the same source.

Comment: I think `Conditions.name LIKE 'prostate'` is very different than `Conditions.name LIKE '%prostate%'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selcuk's comment led me to the correct result. The variables that feed the Where clause needed to be changed to reflect `Conditions.name LIKE '%prostate%'` in the query, therefore:

```
ProstateUpper = '%Prostate%'
ProstateLower = '%prostate%'
GenderMale = '%Male%'
GenderAll = '%All%'
```